# MVC includes/partials (Codeigniter)

Tags: forms, codeigniter, include, view, partial

I've got an issue at the moment where I have two methods and two views. Each method passes it's Db data to a view, as expected with the MVC pattern.

My issue arises because I want one of the views to be a partial, which is included in the other view.

So it looks something like this:

- First view - i.e. a form
- Second view - fragment of form, i.e. list of cities

I want the second view to be it's own unique file, how can I include this in the first form, at any location in the file?

** had to edit as I got the first bit wrong. There is only one controller, with two methods passing data to two views.

Comment: So, you want to include one another view to one view. One controller with two view? Or I am wrong?

Comment: I guess technically embed a view inside a view. But the way the views are generated is independent, just as if they were separate pages. I don't want to break the MVC pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but CodeIgniter has the ability to return a view as data. In the Controller it would look like this:

```
$data = array();
$data['partial'] = $this->load->view('partial_view', $data, true); // the 3rd parameter let's the view return as data
$this->load->view('whole_view', $data);
```

The whole_view file would look something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>View 1</h1>
<?php echo $partial; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The logic, that loads the data for the partial_view could be extracted to a model or so.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the load like this:

view_one.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>View 1</h1>
<?php echo $this->load->view('view_two'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that both have data passed to them from the method, so just including the view throws an undefined variable error

Comment: Than, copy the variables from method 2 and put on method 1. In this form you will get the database query on one method and send it on two separate views.

Comment: please edit your answer $this variable does not exist in views. (get_instance()).

Comment: Yes @Kyslik, it exist. You can try it, and you will see.

Comment: Actualy within a view `$this` refers to CI_Loader and get_instance() refers to the CI_Base() as always.